# Задача с e-olymp

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как найти количество решений в диафантовом уравнение с 3 неизвестными, когда даны a, b, c, d.
Лимит по времени: 0.1c
Лимит по памяти: 64MiB

Монах Карла Великого
Карл Великий, действительно был Великим, так как думал о будущем жителей своей страны. В одну из первых известных школ города Аахена он пригласил в 795 году преподавать математику монаха Алькуина, который своим ученикам предлагал такую задачу:

"100 шеффелей (денежных единиц) разделили между мужчинами, женщинами и детьми и дали при этом мужчинам по 3 шеффеля, женщинам по 2 и детям по пол шеффеля. Сколько было мужчин, женщин и детей?"

Общего решения линейных диофантовых уравнений в те времена еще не знали и довольствовались лишь несколькими решениями, удовлетворяющими условию задачи. У самого Алькуина было приведено лишь одно решение этой задачи: мужчин, женщин и детей было 11, 15 и 74, а задача в действительности имеет 784 решения в натуральных числах.

Мы Вам предлагаем пойти дальше на пути усвоения диофантовых уравнений и решить подобную задачку в следующем виде: "C шеффелей разделили между мужчинами, женщинами и детьми. Мужчинам дали по А шеффелей, женщинам – по B шеффелей, а детям, как и в древние времена, по половине шеффеля."

Сколько решений в натуральных числах имеет эта задача?

Входные данные

В единственной строке заданы три натуральных числа: A, B и C. Все входные данные не превышают 1000.

Выходные данные
Вывести единственное число – ответ задачи.

Пример:
Входные данные
3 2 100
Выходные данные
784

Вот я пробовал тупо перебором но оно непонятно почему не работает.

```
a, b, c = map(int, input().split())
# c = a*x + b*y + 0.5*z
count = 0

for x in range(1, c+1):
    for y in range(1, c+1):
        for z in range(1, c+1):
            if a*x + b*y + 0.5*z == c:
                count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: Где свои попытки?

Comment: Хоть бы вид уравнения показал, что ли...

Comment: `for z in range(1, 2*c+1):`

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы заработало, нужно правильно задать диапазон z

```
for x in range(1, c//a +1):
    for y in range(1, c//b +1):
        for z in range(1, 2 * c + 1):
```

И стоит работать в целых числах (здесь проходит и без этого, при других коэффициентах можно проколоться)

```
        if 2 * a*x + 2 * b*y + z ==  2 * c:
```

При большем диапазоне стоит подумать о более эффективном методе